# SQL Server 2008 Getting a Quarterly data with Pivot

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, pivot

I am trying to get the **SUM** of all the **NetAmount** of every Transaction and I tried using Pivot to Show the **SUM** of the Transaction within a Date Range in **Quarterly**.

```
DECLARE @FromDate DATETIME = '01-01-2016' 
DECLARE @ToDate DATETIME = '12-31-2016'

SELECT CustomerName,
        ISNULL([1],0) AS Q1,
        ISNULL([2],0) AS Q2,
        ISNULL([3],0) AS Q3,
        ISNULL([4],0) AS Q4
FROM
(
    SELECT sc.CustomerName, 
            SUM(si.NetAmount) AS NetAmount,
            CAST('Q' + CAST(DATEPART(QUARTER, si.TransactionDate)AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS Quarterly
    FROM tblSampleSalesInvoices si
        LEFT OUTER JOIN tblSampleCustomers sc ON sc.Id = si.CustomerId
    WHERE si.TransactionDate BETWEEN @FromDate AND @ToDate
    GROUP BY sc.CustomerName, si.TransactionDate
) AS BaseData
PIVOT
(
    SUM(NetAmount)
    FOR Quarterly IN ([1],[2],[3],[4])
)AS Pivoting
```

Here are the contents of my tables.

[image]

And here is the output:

[image]

Comment: Don't your quarterly identifers look like `Q1` not `1`? Run the inner select on it's own and check.

Comment: Also you probably shouldn't be grouping by `si.TransactionDate`, but instead group by the full quarter expression - again run the inner select to observe this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have pointed out, the quarter identifiers should be `Q1`, `Q2`, `Q3`, and `Q4`. Additionally, instead of grouping by the `TransactionDate`, you have to use `DATEPART(QUARTER, si.TransactionDate)`:

```
SELECT
    CustomerName,
    ISNULL([Q1],0) AS Q1,
    ISNULL([Q2],0) AS Q2,
    ISNULL([Q3],0) AS Q3,
    ISNULL([Q4],0) AS Q4
FROM
(
    SELECT sc.CustomerName, 
            SUM(si.NetAmount) AS NetAmount,
            CAST('Q' + CAST(DATEPART(QUARTER, si.TransactionDate)AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS Quarterly
    FROM tblSampleSalesInvoices si
        LEFT OUTER JOIN tblSampleCustomers sc ON sc.Id = si.CustomerId
    WHERE si.TransactionDate BETWEEN @FromDate AND @ToDate
    GROUP BY sc.CustomerName, DATEPART(QUARTER, si.TransactionDate)
) AS BaseData
PIVOT
(
    SUM(NetAmount)
    FOR Quarterly IN ([Q1],[Q2],[Q3],[Q4])
)AS Pivoting
```

Alternatively, you could remove the `SUM` and `GROUP BY` in the `FROM` clause, and let the `PIVOT` handle the aggregation. Also no need to `CAST` to `VARCHAR(MAX)`, use the proper length:

```
SELECT
    CustomerName,
    ISNULL([Q1],0) AS Q1,
    ISNULL([Q2],0) AS Q2,
    ISNULL([Q3],0) AS Q3,
    ISNULL([Q4],0) AS Q4
FROM
(
    SELECT
        sc.CustomerName, 
        NetAmount AS NetAmount,
        CAST('Q' + CAST(DATEPART(QUARTER, si.TransactionDate)AS VARCHAR(1)) AS VARCHAR(2)) AS Quarterly
    FROM #tblSampleSalesInvoices si
        LEFT OUTER JOIN #tblSampleCustomers sc ON sc.Id = si.CustomerId
    WHERE si.TransactionDate BETWEEN @FromDate AND @ToDate
) AS BaseData
PIVOT
(
    SUM(NetAmount)
    FOR Quarterly IN ([Q1],[Q2],[Q3],[Q4])
)AS Pivoting
```

<kbd>[**ONLINE DEMO**](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/503115)</kbd>

Comment: It worked. So in Pivot I need to specify exactly the Column name instead of the name declared after 'AS'

Comment: Right! you need to put the values you get from the `FROM` clause.

Comment: @ZeroCool Sorry, I just noticed that the first and second query is the same. Please see updated answer.

Comment: Thank you sir. Just need to make this Dynamic Pivot now.